# LESS: make to create less files itself

Tags: makefile, less

Goog evening,

I'm completely new to makefiles and worked out a file which fits our needs good but I'm not completely satisfied. We use bootstrap3 and have around 40 customers with differend color settings. That's why we need to compile 40 slightly different css files. Until now, we have the following file structure

- less/customer1.less
- css/customer1.css
- color/customer.less contains bootstraps variables file

customer1.less contains

```
@variables: 'myCompany/color/customer1'; //this is forwarded to where bootrstrap loads the variables template
@import "bootstrap";
@import 'myCompany/modifications';
```

Our makefile

```
SOURCES = $(shell ls less/*.less)
# Files we don't want to be build
SOURCES := $(filter-out less/bootstrap.less, $(SOURCES))
SOURCES := $(filter-out less/a11y.less, $(SOURCES))
TARGETS = $(patsubst less/%.less,css/%.css,$(SOURCES))
DEPEND = $(patsubst less/%.less,make/%.d,$(SOURCES))
css/%.css: less/%.less 
    # First building dependency files
    lessc -M $< $@ > 'make/$*.d'
    # Then building CSS and sourcemap
    lessc -s $< > $@ --source-map=map/$*.css.map --source-map-basepath=map --clean-css
-include $(DEPEND)
all: $(TARGETS)
```

Call

```
$ make all
```

Creates Makefiles in make/, CSS in css/ CSS source-maps in map/ and expects LESS being in less/.

This works but we need to create customerX.less for each customer manually even if the only difference is the assigned color scheme/variables file. 
Make should look in the color folder if there is a file for this customerX and then create (but not overwrite!) customerX.less in less directory.

Any make guru out here know how to do this with make?

Comment: It seems there is still something wrong in above makefile. For customer1 everything is fine. But It does not renew customer2. That behevior depends on the order in the include statemant. If I first include customer2 everything works for this customer but then customer1 is missing. Somebody knows why? Already tryed to set a new variable DEPEND which contains the dependencies. Nevertheless the same problem with dependency order.

Comment: This occurred because I called 'make' and not 'make all'. I've improved the code above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do what you want here with an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).

Something like:

```
less/customer%.less: | color/customer.less
        [ -f '$@' ] || cp $^ $@
```

I don't *think* the `-f` test is strictly necessary there but it shouldn't hurt and is safer.

On a different topic `$(shell ls less/*.less)` can probably be done better with either `$(shell echo less/*.less)` (you don't care about what `ls` does you just want the shell glob expansion) or `$(wildcard less/*.less)`. (Technically shelling out and wildcard are slightly different but I don't know that that will matter for you here.)

Also note that the `all` target will not create these missing less files for you (as `SOURCES` will not contain them as the file didn't exist) but `make css/customer#.css` will create them if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did not have the time to try it, yet, but will do!